# RestTemplate custom headers

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, forgerock

I have a Sprint Boot 2 application that uses RestTemplate to call an external web service for a third-party product called ForgeRock.  It uses the headers to send parameters (not my idea) instead of the body. I keep getting an Error 400 when trying to POST the request.  The body should be empty and I have tried sending null and "{}" with the same results.  FYI, my authenticate method returns null for now while debugging.

```
@PostMapping
public String authenticate(@RequestBody User user) {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  try {
      HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

      ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(authenticateUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
      System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + responseEntity.getBody());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}


private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders(String user, String password) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("X-OpenAM-Username", user);
    headers.add("X-OpenAM-Password", password);
    headers.add("Accept-API-Version", "resource=1.1");
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: You're printing the stack trace, so what does it say?

Comment: Have you been able to build a successful request in something like postman? Turn the `org.apache.http.wire` logger to DEBUG level to see what RestTemplate is sending and compare.

Comment: What does OpenAM access log says?

Comment: Yes, I had built a successful request in Postman.  The stack trace only said 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only getting 400 Bad Request, which I took to mean an issue with the JSON.  However, I discovered the underlying error was actually from ForgeRock that I wasn't sending an FQDN (I was sending IP).  So, the code works as-is if it is sent a FQDN.